# Display data from database and link it to new page with all profile details

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to generate a page with the first and last name of all the profiles in my database. First name should be printed out with a link. The link should be able to be clicked and link to a new page with all of the individuals information.

shownames.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
include 'db.php';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM subjects';
$result = $conn->query($query);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><th>Name</th><th></th><th>Moniker</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td><a href = 'getprofile.php'>".$row["firstName"]." ".$row["lastName"]."</a></td><td>".$row["age"]."</td><td>".$row["moniker"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

getprofile.php:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
    $pkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['firstname']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE firstName =" . $pkey;
    $result = $conn->query($query);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>AGE</th><th>Tattoo</th><th>Moniker</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["firstName"]." ".$row["lastName"]."</td><td>".$row["age"]."</td><td>".$row["tats"]."</td><td>".$row["moniker"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Answer (score 0):

the anchor element you are printing needs to include a query parameter.

```
echo "<tr><td><a href = 'getprofile.php?firstname=" . $row["firstName"]. "'>".$row["firstName"]." ".$row["lastName"]."</a></td><td>".$row["age"]."</td><td>".$row["moniker"]. "</td></tr>";
```